# choose rows from two matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to solve the following problem. I have two matrices A and B and I want to create a new matrix C which consists of the rows of the matrices A and B depending on some condition which is encoded in the array v, i.e. if the i'th entry of v is a one then I want the i'th row of C to be the i'th row of B and if it is a zero then it should be the i'th row of A. I came up with the following solution

```
C = np.choose(v,A.T,B.T).T
```

but it is too slow. One obvious bad thing are the two transposes, but since np.choose does not take an axis argument I don't know how to get rid of them. Any ideas for a fast solution of this problem?

For Example let

```
A = np.arange(20).reshape([4,5])
```

and

```
B = 10 - A
```

Then one could imagine that one wants the matrix C to be the matrix of rows with smallest maximum norm. So we let

```
v = np.sum(A,axis=1)<np.sum(B,axis=1)
```

and then C is the matrix

```
C = np.choose(v,[A.T,B.T]).T
```

which is

```
array([[10,  9,  8,  7,  6],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of A and B, and what you want C to look like?

Comment: i added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a good setup to use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to do the chosing operation based on the mask/binary input data -

```
C = np.where(v[:,None],B,A)
```

That `v[:,None]` part basically extends `v` to broadcastable shape as `A` and `B` allowing the [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to let chosing work along the appropriate axis, `axis=0` in this case for the two `2D` arrays.

Sample run -

```
In [58]: A
Out[58]: 
array([[82, 78, 57],
       [14, 97, 32],
       [72, 11, 49],
       [98, 34, 41],
       [89, 71, 52],
       [34, 51, 55],
       [26, 92, 59]])

In [59]: B
Out[59]: 
array([[55, 67, 50],
       [49, 64, 21],
       [34, 18, 72],
       [24, 61, 65],
       [56, 59, 23],
       [44, 77, 13],
       [56, 55, 58]])

In [62]: v
Out[62]: array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])

In [63]: np.where(v[:,None],B,A)
Out[63]: 
array([[55, 67, 50],
       [14, 97, 32],
       [72, 11, 49],
       [98, 34, 41],
       [89, 71, 52],
       [44, 77, 13],
       [56, 55, 58]])
```

If `v` doesn't strictly consist of `0s` and `1s` only, use `v[:,None]==1` as the first argument with `np.where`.

---

Another approach would be with [`boolean-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) -

```
C = A.copy()
mask = v==1
C[mask] = B[mask]
```

**Note :** If `v` is already a boolean array, skip the comparison against `1` for the mask creation.

Runtime test -

```
In [77]: A = np.random.randint(11,99,(10000,3))

In [78]: B = np.random.randint(11,99,(10000,3))

In [79]: v = np.random.rand(A.shape[0])>0.5

In [82]: def choose_rows_copy(A, B, v):
    ...:     C = A.copy()
    ...:     C[v] = B[v]
    ...:     return C
    ...: 

In [83]: %timeit np.where(v[:,None],B,A)
10000 loops, best of 3: 107 µs per loop

In [84]: %timeit choose_rows_copy(A, B, v)
1000 loops, best of 3: 226 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice ideas. I got roughly the same results benchmarking.